# What is the difference between "devrait" and "doit"?

Tags: sens, conditionnel

- J'ai déjà demandé ça à Anne, qui **devrait** s’en occuper maintenant.
- J'ai déjà demandé ça à Anne, qui **doit** s’en occuper maintenant.

When *devoir* means *probabilité*, how do *doit* and *devrait* have different meanings? Do they both mean "she **must** be taking care of it now"?

Answer (score 4):

*Doit* is the present tense, *devrait* is a conditional.  In your examples  they both imply an action that is likely to happen but not  100% sure and each with a different degree of im(probablity).

- J'ai déjà demandé ça à Anne, qui devrait s’en occuper maintenant.
  Je suppose qu'elle va s'en occuper. <sup>1</sup>
- J'ai déjà demandé ça à Anne, qui doit s’en occuper maintenant.
  Je suis presque sûre qu'elle va s'en occuper. Je suis plus sûre de la réalisation de l'action quand je dis ça. <sup>2</sup>

1  <sub>She may/might be doing it now.</sub>
2 <sub>She must be doing it now</sub>

Comment: Notice that *maintenant* is very unlikely to mean “now” here. It's much more likely that Anne is (now, i.e. from now on) in charge of doing it. To mean “right now” we'd use “en ce moment même”.

Comment: Another alternative for the [1] -> "She _should_ be doing it from now on". J'ai un doute sur la traduction de "maintenant" par simplement "now" dans ce contexte, 'à cette heure' m'aurait paru tout a fait bien traduit par 'now', ici j'y vois plus un 'à partir de maintenant' réduis à 'maintenant' à l'oral (question d'interprétation je suppose).

Comment: @Tensibai I agree with you on the conditional "devrait" translating as "should" or "ought to" rather than "may/might" in English. For instance: "he **should / ought to** be home by now" is more probable than "he **may/might** be home by now" and less probable than "he **must** be home by now".

Answer (score 3):

*(L'anglais suit / English follows)*

Normalement, *doit* veut bien dire « est forcément obligé ; n'a pas de choix ».
En anglais : « must », « has to ».

De l'autre côté, *devrait* veut dire « est obligé par sa conscience ; ferait mieux de ... ». Personne ne la force à s'en occuper, mais on le lui conseille. En anglais : « should », « ought to ».

Le conditionnel sert très souvent à « adoucir » une expression. Dans cet exemple, on dirait probablement « devrait » vu que demander à quelqu'un ne l'engage à rien.

**En plus, il y a une autre interprétation possible.** Il faut dire que *devoir* entraîne souvent des difficultés supplémentaires ... Ici, tes exemples pourraient tous les deux signifier qu'on *croit* que la personne fait ce que tu lui as demandé.

> Tu l'appelles à son bureau ? Mais il est très tard, elle doit être chez elle à cette heure.
>   
> *(Bien qu'elle n'est pas obligée d'être chez toi, on est obligé de croire qu'elle l'est !)*

Dans ce cas le conditionnel modifie le sens de façon parallèle : on *suppose* que c'est le cas.

L'avis de Laure dans sa réponse est que cette interprétation est la bonne, et je suis fort tenté de le croire aussi.

---

Normally, *doit* does indeed mean "must, has to".

Whereas *devrait* means "be obliged by one's conscience; would do well to; should, ought to". No one would force her to take care of it, but they might advise her to.

The conditional often works to "soften" an expression. Going by your example, one would probably say "devrait" since asking someone isn't binding.

**Also, there is another interpretation possible.** It must be said that *devoir* often involves more problems than that... Here, your two examples could both mean that one *believes* her to be doing what you asked her to do. This actually works like English "must":

> Tu l'appelles à son bureau ? Mais il est très tard, elle doit être chez elle à cette heure.
>   
> *You're calling her her work? But it's very late; she must be home at this hour.*
>   
> *(Even though she's not obliged to be home, we're obliged to assume that she is!)*

In this case, the conditional modifies the meaning in a parallel way: *you'd expect* it was the case.

Laure's opinion in the other answer is that this interpretation is the right one, and I'm strongly inclined to agree.

Comment: Je suis tout à fait d'accord avec ce que tu dis dans les 3e et 4e paragraphes. Je dirais par contre que c'est une seule et même chose, l'adoucissement se fait par la supposition.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Ah oui, ce « mais »-là était trompant. Je ne voulais pas nier que le conditionnel sert à adoucir, mais plutôt contourner l'interprétation qu'il y aurait une obligation dans ce cas.

Comment: ...trompeur, était *trompeur*...